# How to pass parameter with double quote inside JSON_EXISTS Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, json, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a table

```
CREATE TABLE json_data(
                       json_col   VARCHAR2(1000), 
                       CONSTRAINT must_be_json CHECK (json_col IS JSON )
                      )
```

Inserted Data into table

```
INSERT INTO json_data VALUES ('{ "abc" : { "fname" : "john" ,"lname" : "rambo" }}')
INSERT INTO json_data VALUES ('{ "abc" : { "fname" : "james" ,"lname" : "bond" }}')
```

Need to select value using below query

```
SELECT json_col FROM json_data 
WHERE JSON_EXISTS(json_col, '$.abc') 
    AND JSON_EXISTS(json_col,'$?(@.abc.name == "john")')
```

works fine without problem, however I need to pass value "John" as parameter like..

```
SELECT json_col FROM json_data 
WHERE JSON_EXISTS(json_col, '$.abc') 
    AND JSON_EXISTS(json_col,'$?(@.abc.name == :johnParam)'
```

where `:johnParam` is a parameter

its not taking as parameter, please help me how to pass `:johnParam` parameter with double quotes

Comment: Is your real question how to use a parameter in a `JSON_EXISTS` expression?

Comment: Yes, with double quote

Comment: There are no double quotes in the data, so what do double quotes have to do with this? The string values don't contain their delimiters. The *real* question should be whether you can use a parameter with `JSON_EXISTS` at all. If you can, you could pass the entire expression as a parameter.

Comment: I mean "john" always with "double quote", because 'john' with 'single quote' does not work. String parameter value always takes single quote

Comment: You assume you can pass a parameter inside a string in the first place. You can't. Parameters aren't string replacement variables, they are similar to Java function parameters. *Maybe* you can pass the entire expression as a parameter and write `AND JSON_EXISTS(json_col,:someParam)` but some SO questions suggest this isn't possible either

Comment: Thank you, can not pass entire expression as a parameter. I am stuck here :(

Comment: You may be able to use the [PASSING clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adjsn/indexes-for-json-data.html#GUID-E3721DDA-23C9-4859-B13B-FAA8544C32F8) to include an external value in the JSON Path expression, eg `json_exists(po_document, '$.PONumber?(@ > $d)' PASSING 1500 AS "d")`. Perhaps you can use a parameter in `PASSING`, eg `PASSING :myParam AS "d")`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to pass a variable to a JSON path in `json_exists`, use the `passing` clause:

```
create table json_data (
  json_col varchar2(1000)
    check ( json_col is json )
);
insert into json_data 
  values ('{ "abc" : { "fname" : "john" ,"lname" : "rambo" }}');
insert into json_data 
  values ('{ "abc" : { "fname" : "james" ,"lname" : "bond" }}');

select json_col from json_data 
where  json_exists ( 
  json_col,
  '$?(@.abc.fname == $johnparam)'
  passing 'john' as "johnparam"
);

JSON_COL                                             
{ "abc" : { "fname" : "john" ,"lname" : "rambo" }}
```

`'john'` in the `passing` clause becomes `:johnParam` in your application.

To search for documents where an attribute equals a specific value, you may find it easier to use simple dot-notation or `json_value` instead:

```
select * from json_data j
where  j.json_col.abc.fname = 'john';

JSON_COL                                             
{ "abc" : { "fname" : "john" ,"lname" : "rambo" }}   

select * from json_data j
where  json_value ( json_col, '$.abc.fname' ) = 'john';

JSON_COL                                             
{ "abc" : { "fname" : "john" ,"lname" : "rambo" }}
```

Then you can replace `'john'` with `:johnParam` as you would for queries against non-JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substitution parameter with ampersand such as `&name` with the following query

```
SELECT json_col
  FROM json_data
 WHERE JSON_EXISTS(json_col, '$.abc?(@.fname == "&name")')
```

where the part `JSON_EXISTS(json_col, '$.abc')` seems redundant. When prompted, enter `john` without quotes as value for `$name`.